# How do I get a client to LAN VPN connection setup on a TL-ER6020 TP-Link Router using a shrew soft client?

Tags: networking, router, vpn

I followed the guide on tp-links support page and I have attempted to call customer support to get this set up.  When I try to connect the client, I get the following output:

```
config loaded for site 'xxxxxxx'
attached to key daemon ...
peer configured
iskamp proposal configured
esp proposal configured
client configured
local id configured
remote id configured
pre-shared key configured
bringing up tunnel ...
negotiation timout occurred
tunnel disabled
detached from key daemon
```

I see that other people have had issues setting up this connection  and I've tried what they suggest without success.  Any other suggestions?

UPDATE: I discovered the VPN Trace Utility for Shrewsoft.  Here is the output for the client:

[iked.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9P8Yf5P9gRYRHhoTVlWa0xUa0k/view?usp=sharing)

[ipsec.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9P8Yf5P9gRYLWFZTWxpVmY1Z3M/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Are you using FQDN as a remote and local ID in the IKE policy ? Also if you are behind NAT on any end, make sure your devices support VPN-Passthrough.

Comment: @drcelus I am using FQDN as both remote & local. Having some trouble accessing the modem on the server end.  I'll let you know when I get through.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem ? Just curious because I am stuck at the same place ...

Comment: @drcelus No, I have not yet solved the problem.  If you solve it, please leave the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @fireligth sadly I didn't have time to work on this problem. I solved it with a software VPN.